# How to get IIS version in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core 2.0.

In c# code on server side I want to check the IIS version where the website is hosted.

Earlier in asp.net the following line gives us the iis version.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"];
```

It was giving me the result like *Microsoft-IIS/10.0*

How to get the desired result in asp.net core ?

Comment: Be aware `ASP.NET Core 2.0` has already reached its **`EOL`** on Oct 1, 2018. Besides, 2.0 doesn't expose any API to do that. Please upgrade your server to **2.2** or above to get this variable.

Comment: Updated my code to asp.net core 2.2, still not able to get the value of this viable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Updated my code to asp.net core 2.2, still not able to get the value of this variable*

If you're using asp.net core 2.2 or above, get the `IServerVariablesFeature` as below:

```cs
var serverVars = HttpContext.Features.Get<IServerVariablesFeature>();
var iisVersion = serverVars == null ? null : serverVars["SERVER_SOFTWARE"];
```

#### Demo:

[image]

Comment: This works in asp.net core 3.x as well.  And for people wondering what other serverVariables can be accessed through this feature, here is a list (albeit not super current) that may prove useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: This worked for me with IIS 10, but not IIS Express. serverVars == null in that case.