# HttpRuntime.IISVersion equivalent in Asp.Net Core 3?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0

I'm porting some code to Asp.Net Core 3 and would like a way to tell which version of IIS the system is running under or even if it is running via IIS, say verses Nginx.

An identical replacement for `HttpRuntime.IISVersion` isn't necessary but it would be nice to get some diagnostic info about what web server the site is running on and what version of the webserver it is.

Is there any way to do this in Asp.Net Core 3?

Comment: Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110283/how-to-get-iis-version-in-asp-net-core/58228598#58228598) help?

Comment: @itminus  I don't know how I missed that.  Thank you, I didn't mean to create a duplicate question.

Comment: I don't believe your question is a duplicate @RonC. ServerVariables (from the other answer) are only available in a request context, while `HttpRuntime` can be queried even during startup. While in some cases they are "equivalent", that's not always the case.